# Exporting to 'INSERT' fails in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I run `SELECT * FROM tech_rd_fin_sec_rep_drvr` and get 20 results.

I go to export these results to 'insert':

[image]

However, my exported .sql files looks like the following:

[image]

I've done this for four other tables and the same issue happens for each.

This surprises me considering I had done this on this environment with these tables only last week and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include: the SQL Developer version you are using; the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for the table and the DML (`INSERT`) statement for your sample data that replicates the problem. Please do not post screenshots of the table structure/data as there may be hidden characters that are causing the issue and we need DDL/DML statements that match your data.

Comment: So, what changed since last week?

Comment: @Littlefoot I moved onto another task. I will update the question when I come back to this.